# Check for Access form list box no selection

Tags: ms-access

I'm trying to see if a list box is empty. I've seen the recommendation to use

```
If IsNull(txtLevel) Then
    MsgBox "No Item is Selected"
```

but this is returning the error MsgBox even when items are select.

Another issue I have had in using other code `If txtLevel.ListIndex = "-1"` or `If txtLevel.listount = 0` is it works well the first time, but if you select and then unselect, this doesn't trigger the error message.

Edit: the answer for me that works is: `If txtLevel.ItemsSelected.Count = 0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use the `.ItemsSelected` property which returns a variant array that contains the row number of the entries that are selected, or the `.Selected` property that returns `True` when the row specified in the parameter is selected.

Comment: Would it be something like If txtLevel.ItemsSelected = 0 then?

Comment: It turned out to be .ItemsSelected.Count that works for me. Then!

Comment: Would you care to upvote any helpful answers, and accept the most helpful?  This ensures that the best answers appear first, and answered questions don't appear in the unanswered lists.

Answer (score 1):

The answer that works is "If txtLevel.ItemsSelected.Count = 0"

Answer (score 0):

Try this code - see if you can see your solution in this.  I left comments to explain what's going on.

- ComboData is a combobox control
- CheckNoComboData is a checkbox control
- CheckSelection is a checkbox control
- CheckNoSelection is a checkbox control

Code:

```
  Dim intIter As Integer
  Dim boolItems As Boolean

  ' Check if there is no Row Source data
  If Nz(Me.ComboData.RowSource, "") = "" Then
    Me.CheckNoComboData = True
  Else
    Me.CheckNoComboData = False
  End If

  ' Check if there is a row source, but no
  ' items resulting from that rowsource
  If Me.ComboData.ListCount = 0 Then
    Me.CheckNoComboData = True
  Else
    Me.CheckNoComboData = False
  End If

  ' Check if any items in the listbox are selected or not
  Items = False
  ' Loop through each item in the combobox
  For intIter = 0 To (Me.ComboData.ListCount - 1)
    ' If its selected, then we know items are selected
    If Me.ComboData.Selected(intIter) Then
      Items = True
      Exit For
    End If
  Next

  ' Return Results
  Me.CheckSelection = Items
  Me.CheckNoSelection = Not Items
```